# Use a class method as an integrand to GSL QAGS

Tags: python, function, class, methods, cython

I want to use a member function of a class for a global function for gsl_function and I don't know how it should be done. Since I now just very basics about C, I know that I have to send the class instance which is the integrand to a void parameter but technically I can not code it in `cython`, it is a cython example.

```
from cython_gsl cimport *

ctypedef double * double_ptr
ctypedef void * void_ptr

cdef double foo(double x, void * params) nogil:
    cdef double alpha, f
    alpha = (<double_ptr> params)[0]
    f = log(alpha*x) / sqrt(x)
    return f


def main():
    cdef gsl_integration_workspace * w
    cdef double result, error, expected, alpha
    w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000)

    expected = -4.0
    alpha = 1

    cdef gsl_function F
    F.function = &foo
    F.params = &alpha

    gsl_integration_qags (&F, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error)
    print "result          = % .18f\n" % result
    print "estimated error          = % .18f\n" % error
```

assuming I have the following class:

```
from math import *
cdef class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, double a=1.2, double b=0.6):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def _integrand(self,double x):
         cdef double self.a = (<double_ptr> params)[0]
         cdef double self.b = (<double_ptr> params)[1]
         return self.a*log(x)+self.b/x**3
    def whole(self, double upper_limit=10,double lower_limit=0):
        cdef gsl_integration_workspace * w
        cdef double result, error, expected, alpha
        w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000)

        expected = -4.0
        params[0] = self.a
        params[1] = self.b

        cdef gsl_function F
        F.function = &self._integrand
        F.params = params

        gsl_integration_qags (&F, lower_limit,upper_limit , 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error)
        return result,error
```

how do I convert `Foo._integrand` to a global function that can be used by `gsl`?

Comment: One question: Shouldn't the last line say `return self.a*log(x)+self.b/x**3`?

Comment: The particular method you want to make global doesn't make any sense outside the context of the instance of the class it is bound to. It depends on ``a`` and ``b``, both of which are instance class attributes.  Why do you want to do what you are asking?

Comment: @aruisdante because it is just an example of my bigger problem. I want to use this integral in a class and I don't know how it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can use `functools.partial` to pass the method like a function pre-defining `self` argument:

```
from functools import partial

foo = Foo()
integrand_func = partial(Foo._integrand, foo)
```

But you **cannot** define such a partial function in C. For this reason I would externalize the integrand and define it as one parameter of your class, instead of an extra method. Note that this is like using a static method, but [Cython does not support it yet](http://docs.cython.org/0.15/src/userguide/limitations.html). Another important tip is to use `log` form `math.h`. See the prototype below:

```
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#cython: nonecheck=False
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double log(double x) nogil

ctypedef double (*function)(double x, void *params)

cdef struct integrandFoo_p:
    double *a
    double *b

cdef struct gsl_function:
    function function
    void *params

cdef double integrandFoo(double x, void *params):
    cdef integrandFoo_p *p=<integrandFoo_p *>params
    cdef double a, b
    a = p.a[0]
    b = p.b[0]
    return a*log(x)+b/(x*x*x)

cdef void trapzd(gsl_function *F, double lower_limit, double upper_limit,
                 int num, double *result, double *error):
    cdef int i
    cdef double x
    f = F[0].function
    p = F[0].params
    result[0] = 0.
    for i in range(num+1):
        x = lower_limit + (upper_limit - lower_limit)*i/num
        if i==0 or i==num:
            result[0] += f(x, p)*0.5
        else:
            result[0] += f(x, p)

    error[0] = 0.

cdef class Foo(object):
    cdef double a
    cdef double b
    cdef double result
    cdef double error
    cdef function f
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1.2
        self.b = 0.6
        self.f = <function>integrandFoo
    cdef void integrate(self, double lower_limit=1, double upper_limit=10):
        #cdef gsl_integration_workspace * w
        cdef double result, error, expected, alpha
        cdef integrandFoo_p p
        cdef gsl_function F

        #w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000)
        p.a = &self.a
        p.b = &self.b
        expected = -4.0

        F.function = self.f
        F.params = &p

        trapzd(&F, lower_limit, upper_limit, 1000, &self.result, &self.error)
        #gsl_integration_qags(&F, lower_limit, upper_limit, 0, 1e-7,
                             #1000, w, &result, &error)
def main():
    foo = Foo()
    print 'HERE', foo.result, foo.error
    foo.integrate()
    print 'HERE', foo.result, foo.error
```

Comment: @ Saullo If I want to add an instance to the class to compute the integral of the given function, how could I do it?

Comment: could `@staticmethod` helps to make integrand independent of the whole class or making a general `integrand` function without a clear given functionality outside of the class and being called in the class that get the class parameters as inputs can solve the problem? –  Dalek

Comment: my problem is that I need to define integrand inside class because not in this example but I need to use other instant inside the class to build up my integrand. However, there are still couple of problems that I can not build your answer with `cython`. For instance, the first error `Cannot assign type 'integrandFoo_p' to 'integrandFoo_p *'` and the second one for `self.f=integrandFoo` it raises `Cannot assign type 'double (double, void *)' to 'function'`, then for `p.a = &self.a` I got this error `Cannot take address of Python variable`.

Comment: you defined instant `integrate` as void but at the end you returned `result` and `error`.

Comment: @Dalek thank you, I've updated the answer with a working version... :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So at the end it seems GSL library can not be called in a cython class, right?

Comment: @Dalek It can, you just have to replace my `trapz()` by the GSL integrator... I left it commented so that you could run the code

Comment: @Dalek did you try to use this solution?

Comment: I ran your code it works but it is not in the framework of my original question. You sent me before a link of one of your answer which you construct two `trapzd` and `poly` functions for integration. I am interested to use the `poly` integration because was more accurate but I couldn't change it to be used for my application. The other problem is that my integrand should be inside the class because I use another instances of the class to build my `integrand` and use the whole class later in my python code. Therefore it doesn't make sense if I define the function outside of the class.

Comment: For original question of integration with `gsl`, I found out I also can do something similar [callback method from C libraries](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Demos/callback) but again I couldn't implement it properly

Comment: I have a working example of `c++` code for using `GSL` in a class, but the problem is that I don't know how to convert header and function wrapper from `c` to `cython`. Could I post it and you kindly help me to make the `cython` version of it work?

Comment: @Dalek sure... all the community will be pleased to help you. Don't forget you can accept this answer and/or upvote it if you liked...

Comment: sometimes people are expecting to have already written code and just modify it but my knowledge of both `cython` and `c` are less than the point I could convert it.

Comment: Should I write it in different post?

Comment: @Dalek [check this wrapper I wrote](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature)... the Cython header is inside [`_cubature.pxd`](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature/blob/master/cubature/_cubature.pxd), which is almost a copy of [the original C header](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature/blob/master/cubature/cpackage/cubature.h)... note that writing the header is relatively easy...

Comment: @Dalek, yes this question is already solved... writing the header is surely another question...

Comment: well it seems people are not motivated to post any answer for my new question!! The other point is that I prefer not have separate header file and the whole header and methods be in a single code.

Comment: I am terribly sorry that I ask you again for help. Could you check out [the new update of my gsl problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513246/wrapping-a-c-library-gsl-in-a-cython-code-by-using-callback)

Comment: @Dalek Sorry for the unavailability.. could we meet [in this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52731/discussion-between-saullo-castro-and-tcapelle) in about 2 hours? Then I can have a look at your problem and discuss it together with you...

Comment: Sure thanks a lot! Just send a notification here I will catch up!

Comment: @dalek could you please [join this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56766/cython)

Comment: Did I lose my chance to discuss about my question?

Comment: @Dalek... please, check the room

Comment: I am trying to convert a class to cython as you may noticed. I posted another question yesterday. Nobody so far answered or commented. Could you please take a look? I need an expert opinion! Sorry again!

Comment: Thanks a lot Saullo! Look forward to your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the 'self's & add a & b to its call signature, and dedent the code.

```
    def _integrand(x, a, b):
        return a*log(x)+b/x**3
```