# wrapping a C library (GSL) in a cython code by using callback

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, cython, gsl

I am a newbie with `cython` and `c`. I want to use cython to speed up the performance of my code. I would like to use `gsl_integration` library in my code for integration. 
update: **test_gsl.pyx**

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    double log(double x) nogil
cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_math.h":
    ctypedef struct gsl_function:
        double (* function) (double x, void * params)
        void * params

cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_integration.h":
    ctypedef struct gsl_integration_workspace
    gsl_integration_workspace *  gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(size_t n)
    void  gsl_integration_workspace_free(gsl_integration_workspace * w)

    int  gsl_integration_qags(const gsl_function * f, double a, double b, double epsabs, double epsrel, size_t limit, gsl_integration_workspace * workspace, double *result, double *abserr)


cdef double do_callback(double x, void* params):
    return (<MyCallback>params).eval(x)

cdef class MyCallback:
    cdef double a
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    cpdef double eval(self, double x):
        return self.a * log(x+1) * x
    def call_gsl(self):
        cdef gsl_integration_workspace* w =gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000)

        cdef gsl_function F
        F.function = &do_callback
        F.params = <void*>self

        cdef double result = 3, error = 5
        gsl_integration_qags(&F, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error)
        print result, error
        gsl_integration_workspace_free(w)
```

This `.pyx` code is compiled with the following `setup.py` file and does not raise any error message:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy
import sys 
ext = Extension("test_gsl", ["test_gsl.pyx"],
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(),
                  "/usr/include/"],
    library_dirs=["/usr/lib/"],
    libraries=["gsl"])

setup(ext_modules=[ext],
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext})
```

or even with the command line:

```
cython test_gsl.pyx
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/vol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages -I/usr/include -I/vol/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c test_gsl.c `pkg-config --cflags gsl` 
gcc -pthread -shared test_gsl.o -L/usr/lib -L/vol/anaconda/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lpython2.7 `pkg-config --libs gsl` -o test_gsl.so
```

when it is import in python as following, it does raise errors:

```
>>> import pyximport; pyximport.install()
(None, <pyximport.pyximport.PyxImporter object at 0x7f0c7e888150>)
>>> import gsl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 431, in load_module
    language_level=self.language_level)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 210, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_dynamic(name, so_path)
ImportError: Building module gsl failed: ['ImportError: /users/dalek/.pyxbld/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gsl.so: undefined symbol: gsl_integration_qags\n']
```

`gsl_integration_qags` has been defined properly, I don't understand why I got this error again?

Comment: I found that it was worth my time to watch [this video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKCjsRDffXo). That is how I just got started. I see nothing in your code that cannot be converted (at a first) glance. Start by trying to convert the `.h` classes and structs into cython classes. Some pointers can be found [on the cython website](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html). But it will all make more sense if you look at the presentation first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compiling it with the below commands:

```
cython test_gsl.pyx
gcc -m64 -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/vol/dalek/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c test_gsl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/test_gsl.o
gcc -pthread -shared -L/usr/lib/ -L/vol/dalek/anaconda/lib -o test_gsl.so  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/test_gsl.o -lpython2.7  -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

If I import `test_gsl` in python without `pyximport`, it works perfectly. Since `pyximport` doesn't support linking against external libraries.

Answer (score 2):

> First Rule: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.
>
> Second Rule: Follow first rule at all cost.
>
> Third Rule: Do not use C++ complex features ( complex in comparison to C - this includes classes) if there is no need for that (even if you are a C++ fanatic like I am). This is especially true if you are mixing C++ with C libraries.

I can't see any reason why C++ classes are necessary in your example, especially because you create an unnecessary indirection (the wrapper) by doing that! If you are coding in compiled language for performance,  unnecessary steps and indirections is exactly want you want to avoid! You are making your life difficult for no reason, especially because is the GSL routines in C that will do 99.9% of the computations in your program. Why not just use something like [cython-gsl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CythonGSL/0.2.1) and resume your code to something like that (taken from cython-gsl example folder). This is much shorter, cleaner and I can't see the reason why it would not perform well given that python is not doing any heavy work (assuming that the function foo() will be converted to C which seems to be the case)!

```
from cython_gsl cimport *

ctypedef double * double_ptr ctypedef void * void_ptr

cdef double foo(double x, void * params) nogil:
    cdef double alpha, f
    alpha = (<double_ptr> params)[0]
    f = log(alpha*x) / sqrt(x)
    return f


def main():
    cdef gsl_integration_workspace * w
    cdef double result, error, expected, alpha
    w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000)

    expected = -4.0
    alpha = 1

    cdef gsl_function F
    F.function = &foo
    F.params = &alpha

    gsl_integration_qags (&F, 0, 1, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error)
    print "result          = % .18f\n" % result
    print "estimated error          = % .18f\n" % error
```

Comment: I don't like complexity too. But what I posted was an example of my bigger problem. I have an MCMC code which calls a class with integration each time and one of the bottleneck was the integration. So I decided to re-write the class in cython. I am afraid I can not avoid the class structure in my code.

Comment: BTW I don't know how I should define `gsl_integration_workspace` to avoid the message?!!

Comment: MCMC in python? :O . I would code it entirely in compiled language given the speed requirements. Before trying cython/c you should test higher level optimization. Adaptive integrations schemes are slow because they are generic. They don't know the shape of the function and usually this implies in more evaluations than necessary for a given accuracy. You probably have a good idea about the shape of the functions you are integrating. So code yourself non-adaptive fast schemes (NR have many examples).

Comment: And if you really want MCMC in python I would use Cosmosis, the Dark Energy survey software (https://bitbucket.org/joezuntz/cosmosis/wiki/Home) because they have developed a pretty nice way to create lots of low level modules and make they talk to each other (using a C++ abstract data type they created)

Comment: Thanks. It seems very interesting, especially since I do weak lensing. I have look into it! However your general attitude is to delete the problem in first place!!

Comment: Fair enough. GSLCython just use the following code to define gsl_struct: cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_integration.h":  
ctypedef struct gsl_integration_workspace int  gsl_integration_qags(gsl_function * f, double a, double b, double epsabs, double epsrel, size_t limit, gsl_integration_workspace * workspace, double *result, double *abserr) nogil

Comment: Is it the way I have defined it? I don't see any difference??!!

Comment: You actually specified an extra struct gsl_integration_struct. From python_gsl code this does not seem necessary

Comment: since you are expert in `c`, do you have any idea why when I build the code could not get access to gsl library ?