# using cython in combination with gsl

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython, gsl

I am using Cython and i wanted to import gnu scientific C library.

```
#gsl_test.pyx

cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_math.h":
double gsl_pow_int (double x, int n)
def gibbs(double k, int t):    
y = gsl_pow_int (k, t)
return y

#setup.py 

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy

include_gsl_dir = "/home/sulabh/include/"
lib_gsl_dir = "/home/sulabh/lib/"


ext = Extension("sl", sources = ["gsl_test.pyx"],include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(),include_gsl_dir],library_dirs=[lib_gsl_dir],libraries=["gsl"])

setup(ext_modules=[ext],cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext})



python setup.py build_ext --inplace

which resulted into sl.o
```

I have entered into python console to import this module by writing `import sl`, but I got an error

```
import sl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/sulabh/lib/libgsl.so.0: undefined symbol: cblas_dasum
```

here is how my package configuration looks like

```
prefix=/home/sulabh/gsl-1.16/..
exec_prefix=/home/sulabh/gsl-1.16/..
libdir=/home/sulabh/gsl-1.16/../lib
includedir=/home/sulabh/gsl-1.16/../include
GSL_CBLAS_LIB=-lgslcblas
```

Name: GSL
Description: GNU Scientific Library
Version: 1.16
Libs: -L/home/sulabh/gsl-1.16/../lib -lgsl ${GSL_CBLAS_LIB} -lm -lm
Cflags: -I/home/sulabh/gsl-1.16/../include

can anybody help

Comment: take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513246/wrapping-a-c-library-gsl-in-a-cython-code-by-using-callback). It is an example of how to call gsl functions in cython.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "gslcblas" to the list of libraries in the function call `Extension`, i.e.

```
ext = Extension(...,libraries=["gsl", "gslcblas"])
```

Or other BLAS library you'd like to add.

Comment: ha ha today i understood what accepting really means.